# Xpath or CSS Selector to select all child nodes that come before a specific child node

Tags: node.js, xpath, css-selectors, apify

I have this following html data :

```
 <span id="description">
    <p>description</p>
    <p>description</p>
    <p></p>
    <h3>title1</h3>
    some text. <br>
    <br>
    some text.
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div>data</div>
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <strong>data</strong>
    <br>
    some text.
    <br>
    <br>
    some text.
    <p></p>
 </span>
```

I need to get all the `p` tags up to first `h3` tag.

I tried Xpath `//span[@id="description"]` which will get all the children of the `span` tag, which I dont need.

I also tried `//span[@id="description"]/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::p` which only returned first preceding `p` tag. Also selecting individual p nodes and then combining them are not feasible since different pages will have different number of p nodes before the first h3.

Then I tried with CSS selectors and remove function, `$('#description').clone().children('div,h3').remove().end().html().trim()`. Which didnt work well, since I cant select text nodes with it.

Is there anyway I can split the data with these `h3` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression

```
//span[@id="description"]/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::p
```

should work.

A similar expression

```
//span[@id="description"]/h3[1]//preceding-sibling::p
```

should also work.

Also try this one:

```
//span[@id="description"]/p[following-sibling::h3[contains(text(),"title1")]]
```

Comment: I am using the code in apify platform, when I use "//span[@id="description"]/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::p", it automatically read as "//span[@id="description"]/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::p[1]", and wont return all the p tags before h3[1].

Comment: @neenkart I don't have apify so I can't test it myself, unfortunately. Did you try the other options in the answer?

Comment: Ok. Yes, I did, still it returned only the first occurrence. So, I am going to declare atleast 5 occurrence as variables and concatenate them to a single variable, in some pages I may lose data, still hoping that will work. Thank you.